# What does Test Explorer actually start?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, testing, asp.net-web-api

I'd like to run some tests on a web page front end I made to a ASP.NET RESTful Web API, by using Selenium. I'm assuming right now that when I click "Run All" in the test explorer, that it's starting my web server, loading my web page (by going to it's url using a Selenium driver), and then accessing it. I'm not sure what "Run All" actually does though, and would like a little more information. What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

"Run All" runs *all tests* in the solution irrespective what they do.

Tests are methods marked `TestMethod` in public classes marked with `TestClass` attribute. Test runner skips tests marked with `Ignore` attribute (and hence not run them when you "Run All").

If you test method tries to access local web server indeed it will force start of the server and load the page.

Comment: So even if it's a test method marked selenium, which navigates to a web page in another project, and then that webpage makes a HTTP request to a local web server, it'll still load everything?

Comment: @ian.p.swift I don't know what it means "a test method marked selenium", so I can't comment on your question. Sample (3-5 lines including all attributes) or "test method" in the question could help someone to answer that.